# If $\lambda_{\max} = n$, then $n\times n$ positive, reciprocal matrix $A$ is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

At the end of [chapter 3](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-2217(02)00227-8) ([PDF](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/meetings/mathofranking/ref/saaty1.pdf)), the author states the following.

Suppose we have $n \times n$ matrix $A$ having only positive elements and satisfying the property $a_{ij}=1/a_{ji}$ (a matrix satisfying this property is called a reciprocal matrix).If its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ is equal to $n$, then the matrix $A$ satisfies the property (consistency property) $a_{ij} a_{jk} = a_{ik}$ where $i,j,k = 1,2,\dots,n$.

I'm not convinced this theorem is true. Could anyone help, please?

Comment: Why downvote this question? Is it that obvious?

Comment: I'm asking how do we know that the matrix $A$ is consistent, knowing that it is reciprocal, positive and that $\lambda_{max}=n$. I'm just not convinced there are no inconsistent matrices satisfying this property. It's a bit surprising conclusion.

Comment: If you change those numbers, then it will generally no longer be reciprocal either, and why would the maximum eigenvalue remain unchanged if you alter the entries of the matrix? In either case, it's clear that the theorem won't apply.

Comment: @user4205580 It would be helpful if you explicitly mention that the link contains a proof of this claim.  The phrasing of your question suggests that they simply state this with no justification, but in fact a substantial argument is already given in the paper, so you should indicate which part of that proof you weren't able to follow.

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive and reciprocal matrix whose maximum eigenvalue is $n$.

We show that $A$ is consistent by showing that there exists a vector $\mathbf{w}=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ such that $(A)_{ij}=\frac{w_i}{w_j}$ for all $i,j$.

The vector that we will see works is any eigenvector $\mathbf{w}=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ for the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_\max$ of $A$. By the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), $\mathbf{w}$ is always positive, i.e., each entry is positive.

Let $W$ be the matrix with $(W)_{ij}=\frac{w_i}{w_j}$. Let $E$ be the matrix defined by $(E)_{ij}=(A)_{ij}\frac{w_j}{w_i}$. Then $E$ is also positive and reciprocal and $W\circ E = A$, where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product of $W$ and $E$ (i.e., the entry-wise product).

Now let's add up the entries in row $i$ of $E$. Since $\mathbf{w}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_\max$ we have \begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{j=1}^n (E)_{ij} &=& \sum_{j=1}^n (A)_{ij}\frac{w_j}{w_i} \\ &=& \frac{1}{w_i} \sum_{j=1}^n (A)_{ij}w_j \\ &=& \frac{1}{w_i} \lambda_\max w_i \\ &=& \lambda_\max.\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore the sum of all entries of $E$ is equal to $n\lambda_\max$.

On the other hand, since $E$ is a positive reciprocal matrix, the diagonal entries are equal to $1$. Hence the sum of all entries of $E$ is equal to \begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i,j=1}^n (E)_{i,j} &=& \sum_{i=1}^n (E)_{i,i} + \sum_{1\leq i< j \leq n} \left ((E)_{i,j} + (E)_{i,j}^{-1}\right)\\ &\geq& n+{n\choose 2} 2,\end{eqnarray*}
where the inequality follows from the fact that $x+x^{-1}\geq 2$ for all positive $x$ with equality if and only if $x=1$.

So we have $n+{n\choose 2} 2 \leq n\lambda_\max$ with equality if and only if each $(E)_{i,j}=1$.

But if we assume that $\lambda_\max =n$, then $n+{n\choose 2} 2 = n^2$ and so *we do* have equality. Therefore $(E)_{i,j}=1$ for all $i,j$ from which we conclude that $A=W$ and so $A$ is consistent.

Comment: It looks easier to understand, but first: using the definition of consistency ($a_{ij} a_{jk}=a_{ik}$) - why is it true that IF a matrix $A$ is consistent, then it must also have a ratio form $A=(w_i / w_j)$? The implication in the other direction is obvious.

Comment: @user4205580 A consistent matrix needn't have that form, e.g., take the identity matrix.

Comment: It's stated as theorem 2.2, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wct10TlbbIUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT50&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) - it's a book of the same author as of the article in my question.

Comment: @user4205580 I guess you mean Theorem 2.1, but that needs $A$ to be positive as well as consistent.  In that case, take $w_j =a_{1j}^{-1}$ for all $j$. You can then use consistency of $A$ to show that $w_i/w_j=a_{ij}$.

Comment: Is $w$ unique? I mean, suppose we know a matrix has eigenvalue 3. Does it have exactly one, unique eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 3 or it can have many?

Comment: No $\mathbf{w}$ is not unique, but any other $\mathbf{w}^\prime$ that works is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{w}$. In general if $\mathbf{w}$ is an eigenvector for a matrix then $c\mathbf{w}$ is another eigenvector with the same eigenvalue for any nonzero $c\in \mathbb{R}$. However notice that the $c$'s cancel in $cw_i/cw_j$. On the other hand, if $A$ is positive and consistent and $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector so that $a_{ij}=w_i/w_j$ for all $i,j$, then $A\mathbf{w}=n\mathbf{w}$, and so this $\mathbf{w}$ has to be an eigenvector for $n$.