# Is there a name for this special matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

$$C_{n\times n}={\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x_{12} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    {x_{12}}^{-1} & 1 & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    {x_{1n}}^{-1} & {x_{2n}}^{-1} & \dots  & 1
\end{bmatrix}}$$

Criteria

$$x_{ab} = \frac{1}{x_{ba}}, \qquad x_{ab}>0, \qquad x_{aa} = 1$$

Alternatively

$$C \cdot C^{T} =  \underline1$$

I know that this matrix models currency exchange (without commission or fluctuation). So I'm guessing it's called a currency matrix or a trade matrix. I'm just after a name so I can search its properties. I couldn't spot it in the [Matrix Reference Manual](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/special.html).

I'm curious about some of its algebraic properties, for example, it has only 1 non-zero eigenvalue. What does this eigenvalue signify?

$$\text{Eigenvalues of} \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 6 & 30  & 210 \\
    1/6 & 1 & 5  & 35 \\
    1/30 & 1/5 & 1 & 7 \\
    1/210 & 1/35 & 1/7  & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 0,0,0,4$$

Any help, ideas, advice greatly welcome.

Comment: I think you mean $C\cdot C^T$ instead of $C\cdot C^{-1}$, and it's $\underline n$ instead of $\underline 1$.

Comment: Also you use $j$ both as a dummy variable and the size of the matrix.

Comment: you're right I do mean $C^T$!
though surely element-wise products of $C$ and $C^T$ would be 1 everywhere?

Comment: Oh I see but product of matrices doesn't work element-wise, that is very unusual. If you mean element-wise it would be better to indicate it.

Comment: The standard notation is that a dot means matrix multiplication, if you want elementwise multiplication you should use some other symbol and explicitly state it

Comment: Is there a standard notation for element-wise product?

In the Matrix Reference Manual he (Mike Brookes) used a dot product so I went for that.

Comment: @BenCrossley https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: Some sources call this *reciprocal* matrices.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1327183/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is a positive reciprocal matrix

to be an exchange matrix the additional condition that $a_{ij} \times a_{jk} = a_{ik}$ is required

$C$ is then a Positive Saaty-consistent Reciprocal matrix (PS-cR)

the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ PS-cR matrix are $n,0,..,0$

Thank you @Algebraic Pavel for the term reciprocal.

Answer (score -3):

It is laplacian matrix which is normally I-A, where A is adjacency matrix.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix

Comment: No. That is false. Have you read Wiki article??

Comment: The example on that page does not fit the criteria. The leading diagonal should be 1 and non-diagonal elements should be the inverse of their "transpose element"

Comment: Sorry, I mean normalised laplacian. Imagine currency as set of point on graph connecect each currency with edge with weight eqals negative of exchange rate. The normalised laplacian of this graph will be your matrix.

Comment: @user569688 even then, $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ which is not desired.
They are supposed to be inverse.
Reciprocal Matrices seems to be the correct term.